# display more than one row mysql

Tags: php

I am now doing the search function, which is search by ID.
For example, there are ID 791481, 791431, 791474. If I input 791481, it is able to show the record in the table.

Now I want to input 7914, it is able to show all the record which has the ID which starts with 7914, include (791481, 791431, 791474). How can I do it?

Here is my code

```html
function getByItem($conn){
 global $resArray;

 $id = $_GET["id"];

 //for a item id, we need
 //1. item info
 //2. lastest item in out record and related report
 //3. lastest item repair record 

 $query = "SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE item_id LIKE'".$id."%'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

 $resArray["status"] = "ok";
 if($result){
  if($result->num_rows > 0){
   $resArray["item"]=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   }
  
  
 }else{
  $resArray["status"] = "fail";
 }

 $query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `inoutrecord`  WHERE item_id LIKE'".$id."%') AS I NATURAL JOIN `report` ORDER BY report_date DESC";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 //$resArray["echo1"] = $query;

 if($result){
  if($result->num_rows > 0){
   $resArray["inoutrecord"]=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  }
 }else{
  $resArray["error"] = mysqli_errno($conn).":".mysqli_error($conn);
  $resArray["status"] = "fail";
 }


 $query = "SELECT * FROM `repairrecord` WHERE item_id LIKE'".$id."%' ORDER BY rr_date DESC";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 //$resArray["echo2"] = $query;


 if($result){
  if($result->num_rows > 0){
   $resArray["repairrecord"]=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  }
 }else{
  $resArray["error"] = mysqli_errno($conn).":".mysqli_error($conn);
  $resArray["status"] = "fail";
 }

}
```